# Apache 2.4.37: AllowEncodedSlashes On not working even after added to VirtualHost

Tags: apache

I have read all the related posts and they don't seem to solve my problem. I'm running XAMPP for Windows. I'm writing a rest api that needs to accept a parameter that may have embedded slashes. I have set AllowEncodedSlashes On in both httpd.conf and http-vhosts.conf but it is still not working (BTW - yes - stopped and re-started appache!). Any help would be appreciated. - Thanks.

In httpd.conf:

...

```
ServerRoot "C:/xampp/apache"
AllowEncodedSlashes On
```

In http-vhosts.conf: 
...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/odie/public"  
    ServerName odie
    AllowEncodedSlashes On
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi - not to this specific problem but I just answered my own question with a work-around that I've been using instead. Hope you find it useful!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to solve this specific issue - but I realized I was perhaps approaching this incorrectly. Instead of trying to change server settings, I instead have been encoding/decoding to/from base-64. This allows me to pass any character without any further grief.

In my case I'm using Angular on the front end and PHP on the backend.

The Angular code is:

```
 private encodeParameter(parm: string) {
        if (!parm) {
            return null;
        }
        return btoa(parm);
    }
```

The PHP code is:

```
  public static function decode_parameter($parameter){
            return base64_decode($parameter); 
        }
```